# Synchronization failed: access denied to azure compute emulator

Tags: azure, emulation

It seems like the Azure Compute Emulator does not inherit the permissions from the Visual Studio process. How can i correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution: I force the shutdown of fabric by connecting the Windows Azure SDK Command prompt as Administrator:

```
csrun /devfabric:shutdown
```

and do a clean

```
csrun /devfabric:clean
```

and after deploy the solution again and restart the devfabric that solve the problem but i don't really know what happened because i was using Visual Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator? If not ,you won't be able to connect to the emulator.

Comment: I am running as Administrator, i had another error that i didn't mentioned in the post i discover now is unable to access to dfservice when i tried to shutdown the emulator.